# INCLUDE environment variable is empty when installing lxml

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy, environment-variables, lxml

I'm currently running python 3.4.3 and I'm trying to install lxml so I can install scrapy. When I use `pip install lxml` or try to install it from a pre-compiled .whl file the installation terminates and gives the error: INCLUDE environment variable is empty. INCLUDE is not present in the list of system environment variables, so I guess I'll have to add it manually. What should be in this variable or does someone know another way to install lxml or scrapy that would circumvent this error?
[output when trying to install lxml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQihY.png)

Comment: Have you followed http://lxml.de/installation.html#ms-windows ?

Comment: Yes, i have and it still didn't work. However, the pre-compiled .exe files from pypi have done the trick and installed lxml, so problem solved. Would still like to know how to really fix this so i don't have to use an executable as a workaround though....

Comment: I suggest you report your issue to lxml directly (I can only speak for scrapy here)

Comment: Please, consider adding your current solution as a response.